# Store checkbox group values as a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am trying to store the values of selected checkboxes on a multi page form so I can include these on the final page of the form (and in the email that is sent to the site owner).

I have worked out how to display the values, but saving them for later has got me stumped. I'm learning as I go so I wouldn't be surprised if this is quite easy...

This is the code I'm using:

```
<?php foreach ($_POST['fooby'] as $key => $entry) {
                if(is_array($entry)){
                    print $key . ": " . implode(',',$entry) . "<br>";
                }
                else {
                    print $key . ": " . $entry . "<br>";
                }
            } ?>
```

And this is the result I get:

```
1: Minor Service £129
2: plus MOT £35
```

That's exactly what I'm after - though I don't need the numbers at the beginning. How do I save that information for later?

With the updated code below, I now get the following result:

```
Minor Service £129
plus MOT £35
```

That's perfect, but I'm struggling to work out how to store that information to a session variable. I should point out that the values returned from the form are dynamic and unknown beforehand. There might also be 10 items in the array, not just the two shown above.

What I have so far:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['fooby'])){
foreach ($_POST['fooby'] as $entry) {
if(is_array($entry)){
$dokval = implode(',',$entry) . "<br>";
echo $dokval; //echoes the expected result on the page
$_SESSION['dokvalues'] = $dokval; //only stores the last item
}
else {
print $entry . "<br>"; //not rewritten this part yet
}
}
}   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply insert these values in hidden input elements in a form on the following pages to use them again:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key1; ?>" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key2; ?>" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop iterates through the array and for each iteration `$key` variable is the current index and `$entry` is the value of that index. The numbers in the list are just representation of index values. If you don't need them, you can go for this:

```
<?php foreach ($_POST['fooby'] as $entry) {
        if(is_array($entry)){
            print implode(',',$entry) . "<br>";
        }
        else {
            print $entry . "<br>";
        }
    } ?>
```

The keys will still stay in $_POST['fooby'] array.

Comment: Thanks, that get's me the information I'm after, but how do I save it?

Comment: @SteveB What do you mean by "save it"?

Comment: Store that information so I can display it on the final form page.

Comment: there are lots of ways to do that - write the vales to the database, to the file, to the session, pass as arguments by reference. It all depends on the logic of the code you're writing. Sorry, but you have to read the PHP documentation and decide for yourself.

Comment: I've figured out how to store the results to a variable. As I thought it was pretty easy, when I echo the variable it displays on the current page perfectly. However, when I save the variable to the session then echo the session on another page, it only displays the last entry from the list. I know I need to use a session array, but have no clue how to implement it in this situation. I'll update the original post with the code I currently have.

Comment: @SteveB Session information is stored in `$_SESSION` arrays. If you store an array inside a session variable, you need to call the variable as multidimensional array, like `$_SESSION["a"]["b"]`. To iterate through an array, use `foreach`. Sorry, but it seems to me like you lack the basic knowledge of PHP. Please consider reading the PHP manual on arrays (http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) to gain basic understanding of arrays. Same goes for sessions (http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but as I said I am learning as I go along - hence why I am asking here.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $entry holds one value of the array each time the foreach loop iterates. So the variable $dokval will also hold only one value, which it echos each time the loop iterates. By the time you look at the session variable it's value is going to be the last value that $dokval held. Make $dokval an array and push the $entry value into it. [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php). Also, make sure you start a session at the beginning of every page you want to use the $_SESSION variable.

Jeff